# XLRD splitting comma separated values of a cell

Tags: python, xlrd

I am using XLRD library to read a particular cell of an excel sheet. This cell might or might not have multiple comma separated values.

[image: comma separated values in a cell]

Please find below my code snippet

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from argparse import ArgumentParser as parser

parse = parser()
parse.add_argument('-p', '--path', action='store', dest='path', help='mention the excel sheet path')
args = parse.parse_args()

excelList = []

book = open_workbook(args.path)
dep_cms = book.sheet_by_index(1)
for row_index in range(1, dep_cms.nrows):
    excelList.append(dep_cms.cell(row_index, 8).value)

print(excelList)

for name in excelList:
    print('Dependent CMS is {}'.format(name))
```

It is printing output like this...

```
['187013, 187014, 187015']
Dependent CMS is 187013, 187014, 187015
```

It is treating comma seperated values as a single string.

The ideal output must be like below

```
['187013', '187014', '187015']
Dependent CMS is 187013
Dependent CMS is 187014
Dependent CMS is 187015
```

How to split them into CS values? I know we can use split to split the string. But how to use it in this context?

Regards

---

**PS:**

Based on suggestion in comments section I have tried split

The result was like this

```
[['187013', ' 187014']]
Dependent CMS is ['187013', ' 187014']
```

If I use space instead of comma as delimiter in split, the result is as follows

```
[['187013,', '187014']]
Thy name is ['187013,', '187014']
```

It is creating an array inside an array which is not what I want.

Based on suggestion of an answer, the following snippet has worked.

```
excelList.extend([x.strip() for x in dep_cms.cell(row_index, 8).value.split(',')])
```

Comment: I think this will work  `excelList.extend(dep_cms.cell(row_index, 8).value.split(','))`

Comment: @abhilb I have updated the question with result based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
excelList = []
for row_index in range(1, dep_cms.nrows):    
    excelList.extend([x.strip() for x in dep_cms.cell(row_index, 8).value.split(',')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this snippet will help. It works by separating out name by commas and making that new list into an array.

```
name = ['187013, 187014, 187015']
names = name[0].split(",") # This separates the first el of name on the comma
for id in names:
  print ("Dependent CMS is " + id.strip())

# prints:
Dependent CMS is 187013
Dependent CMS is 187014
Dependent CMS is 187015
```